# GraphQL - Apollo - Android - Kotlin - Custom types are not getting generated even after specifying them in build.gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, build.gradle

I am using Apollo Client and Graph Ql for my project, I am trying to use `CustomTypeAdapter` and map one of the fields present in `schema` to a custom field. But Custom Type generated does not contain the value that I specify in `build.gradle`.

Below is my app level `build.gradle`

```
 apollo {
        generateKotlinModels.set(true) // or false for Java models
        customTypeMapping = [
                "PersonDetail": "com.task.databasepoc.models.Person"
        ]
    }
```

Below is my project level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath "com.apollographql.apollo:apollo-gradle-plugin:2.0.3"
    }
```

Below is my `CustomTypeAdapter`:

```
object TypeAdapter : CustomTypeAdapter<Person> {
        override fun decode(value: CustomTypeValue<*>): Person {
            return value as Person
        }

        override fun encode(value: Person): CustomTypeValue<*> {
            return CustomTypeValue.fromRawValue(value)
        }


    }
```

I am trying build `ApolloClient` as shown below:

```
fun getApolloClient(): ApolloClient {
        val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
            //.addInterceptor(AuthHeaderInterceptor(authStorageService))
            //.addInterceptorInterceptor(CorrelationIdInterceptor(correlationIdProvider))
            .connectTimeout(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build()
        return ApolloClient.builder()
            .serverUrl("serverUrl")
            .okHttpClient(okHttpClient)
            .addCustomTypeAdapter(CustomType.PersonDetail, TypeAdapter)
            .build()
    }
```

`CustomType` class does not contain `PersonDetail`.

I have tried `rebuilding`, `syncing` everything but no use.

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Did you get a chance to solve the issue?. I am also facing the same issue!

Comment: Could you please share the Person Model? Whether you are extending ScalarType?

Comment: @Nithinjith were you able to fix this issue, I did not use this way

Comment: I want to pass a JSONObject in the input filed of Any. But I think we need a scalarType JSON for passing JSON data

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue came after I upgraded the library from **1.X.X** to **2.5.7** and after trying many solution this works for me

```
apollo {
    generateKotlinModels = false
    customTypeMapping = ['JSONObject' :"org.json.JSONObject" ]
}
```

Also need to change your import from

```
import com.apollographql.apollo.response.CustomTypeAdapter
import com.apollographql.apollo.response.CustomTypeValue
```

to

```
import com.apollographql.apollo.api.CustomTypeAdapter
import com.apollographql.apollo.api.CustomTypeValue
```